# Browser and recognition of some chars

Tags: javascript, browser, ascii, keyboard-events

I'm doing some Javascript experiments about chars recognition. I'm asking myself some questions about characters recognition in browsers (with Javascript mainly).

If with Javascript it's easy to get value of char pressed (`keypress` event for example), there is some chars which they're not recognize like `` ` ``, `^` or `¨`.

First, i'm trying to understand why (i've some ideas but I need to know what you think on this topic) and if someone have a solution for me about how to do that...

maybe i'm just doing things wrong but...

My code below, jQuery (not sure it's important). Nothing is returned on keys i've given above.

```
$(window).on('keypress', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Thanks for answers ;).

Comment: `e` in your code is an `Event` object, not char pressed

Comment: Yes i Know. But contains all informations i want to see for testing. Code isn't a problem here but thanks :).

Comment: This is a whole large concept. View : https://github.com/nostrademons/keycode.js

Comment: Don’t confuse “keys” with “characters”.